# Understanding Django GenericForeignKey and GenericRelation

Tags: django, django-models

I'm building vocabulary and have following models:

```py
class Word(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=75)

class EnNoun(Model):
    word = OneToOneField(Word)

class FrNoun(Model):
    word = ForeignKey(Word)
    gender = CharField()
```

Same word can be in both `EnNoun` and `FrNoun`. Is it possible to fetch result for given word for both `EnNoun` and `FrNoun`, using the least number of queries (there will be more similar classes for language and part of speech, like `ItAdverb`)?

How to store translation from one lang to another (querying 20+ tables is not an option).

Are `GenericForeign` keys of any use? How can I use them in general?

I have the following translation class:

```py
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Translation(Model):
    from_content_type = ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name='from_word_content_type')
    from_object_id = UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4)
    from_word = GenericForeignKey('from_content_type', 'from_object_id')

    to_content_type = ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name='to_word_content_type')
    to_object_id = UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4)
    to_word = GenericForeignKey('to_content_type', 'to_object_id')
```

But it doesn't work:

> Field 'to_word' does not generate an automatic reverse relation and therefore cannot be used for reverse querying. If it is a GenericForeignKey, consider adding a GenericRelation.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

GenericForeignKey tries to give you a `ForeignKey` behavior but instead to be against one type of object, they do it for a set of object types (that's why they are defined with 2 columns, 1 to keep the `primary_key` and another to keep the `content_type`).

`GenericRelation` is the reverse relation of a `GenericForeignKey`, because Django does not automatically create reverse relations for `GenericForeignKeys` (unlike `ForeignKeys`) you have to setup them manually.

I'm not very familiar with the best-practices in translations/vocabulary staff, but if you want to approach the problem with `GenericRelations` and `GenericForeignKeys`, one way to do it would be:

```
class Word(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=75)
    nouns = GenericRelation('WordNoun', content_type_field='noun_ct', object_id_field='noun_id')

class WordNoun(Model):
    word = ForeignKey(Word)
    noun_ct = ForeignKey(ContentType,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        #this is optional
        limit_choices_to = {"model__in": ('EnNoun', 'FrNoun')}
    )
    noun_id = PositiveIntegerField()
    noun = GenericForeignKey('noun_ct', 'noun_id')

class EnNoun(Model):
    word = OneToOneField(Word)

class FrNoun(Model):
    word = ForeignKey(Word)
    gender = CharField()
```

We are basically creating a model keeping word-noun relations,
this give is the following

```
# Having some word
word = Word.objects.get(pk=1)

# With 1 query you can get a list with
# all WordNoun objects for this word.
word_nouns = word.nouns.all()
```

The problem with this approach is that after you get the `word_nouns` list,
accessing a single `noun` instance will make a new query.

```
for word_noun in word.nouns.all():
    print word_noun.noun #this will make a query
```

One way to slightly optimize this is to use `prefetch_related`, so if a single `word` has 3 `word_nouns` (lets say 1 `EnNoun` and 2 `FrNoun`).

Then instead of 4 queries - 1 for the `word_nouns` and 3 for each `noun`, we optimize it to 3 queries - 1 for the `word_nouns` and 2 for each `contenty_type` (`EnNoun` and `FrNoun`)

```
for word_noun in word.nouns.all().prefetch_related('noun'):
    print word_noun.noun #this will not make a query
```

The difference is that the number of queries will now depends on the number of different `ContentTypes`, rather than the number of related `WordNoun` objects.

This scales nicely when you have several `Nouns` from one `contenty_type` in the list you are prefetching, but it will make no difference if you have 1 `Noun per` contenty_type`.

Another approach that I can think of is to use the following model structure:

```
class Word(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=75)

class WordNoun(Model):
    LANG_CHOICES = (
        ('en', 'English'),
        ('fr', 'French'),
    )
    word = ForeignKey(Word)
    lang = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=LANG_CHOICES)
    gender = CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, default='')


#Now accessing all word_nouns would be as easy as:
word_nouns = word.wordnoun_set.all()
```

Comment: OK. Thank you. I think in this case GenericForeignKey is not efficient. But I'm doing translation table now. And I think it is the case. See update

Comment: When you get this `to_word` error? Seems like you are trying to make some kind of filtering? And if you are only using the `Word` class for `from_word` and `to_word` attributes, then you can safely use normal `ForeignKey` instead of `GenericForeignKey`.

Comment: I used get_or_create. How do I preform filtering on generic keys?

Comment: If you add `related_query_name` to a GenericRelation check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations). However you cant use `to_word` and `from_word` directly in `.filter()` more in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey), and thats what `get_or_create` is doing (trying to filter) thats why you get the error. You have to use the `content_type` and `object_id` fields for `get_or_create` or `.filter()`.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to add several `GenericForeignKey` to the same model. This would allow you to create a "link" between objects with generic type. I give an example latter. I modified your example to create something more useful in my sense. The table `Translation` create links between French and English words. Words are stored in classes `EnVerb`, `FrVerb`, `EnNoun` and `FrNoun`. Without `GenericForeignKey`, you would have to create two translation models: `TranslationVerb` and `TranslationNoun`. But in the following code, I show a generic translation model working for both verbs, and nouns. I hope it makes sense!

More technically, you forgot to add the `GenericRelation` field. Also, they must specify the new names of the fields `content_type` and `object_id` in the `GenericRelation` field of the related objects.

#### EXAMPLE

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

Translation(models.Model):
    fr_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="fr_content_type")
    fr_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    fr_word = GenericForeignKey('fr_content_type', 'fr_object_id')

    en_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="en_content_type")
    en_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    en_word = GenericForeignKey('en_content_type', 'en_object_id')

class FrVerb(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    translation = GenericRelation(Translation, content_type_field='fr_content_type', object_id_field='fr_object_id')

class FrNoun(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    translation = GenericRelation(Translation, content_type_field='fr_content_type', object_id_field='fr_object_id')

class EnVerb(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    translation = GenericRelation(Translation, content_type_field='en_content_type', object_id_field='en_object_id')

class EnNoun(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    translation = GenericRelation(Translation, content_type_field='en_content_type', object_id_field='en_object_id')
```

You can use this to create generic translations between models :

```
from polls.models import *      

EnNoun(name='tree').save()                                                                                                                       
FrNoun(name='arbre').save()                                                                                                                      
EnVerb(name='be').save()                                                                                                                         
FrVerb(name='etre').save()                                                                                                                       

trans1 = Translation(fr_word=FrNoun.objects.first(), en_word=EnNoun.objects.first())                                                              
trans2 = Translation(fr_word=FrVerb.objects.first(), en_word=EnVerb.objects.first())
```

Now `trans1` is used to link 'tree' and 'arbre' and `trans2` to link 'be' et 'être' while these objects belongs to different models !